# How do I make row objects value into every single column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Columns are like:

```
| index | nutrition per 100g |
|:------:| -----:|
| 0    | {'energy': 81.12946131894766, 'fat': 2.14013926351589, 'protein': 6.914436593565535, 'salt': 0.055978167389859, 'saturates': 0.36534716195613903, 'sugars': 5.086341034361439} |
| 1 | {'energy': 477.09640393594606, 'fat': 23.412485931109796, 'protein': 7.625491714677334, 'salt': 0.5486205522805531, 'saturates': 3.425053768233838, 'sugars': 14.298442949953758}|
```

I want like this:

```
| index | energy | fat | protein | salt | saturates | sugars |
|:----|:---- |:------:| -----:|----:|----:|----:|
|0 |  81.12946131894766 | 2.14013926351589    | 6.914436593565535 | 0.055978167389859 | 0.36534716195613903 | 5.086341034361439 |
| 1| 477.09640393594606 | 23.412485931109796    | 7.625491714677334 | 0.5486205522805531 | 3.425053768233838 | 14.298442949953758 |
```

Comment: Please past your data properly here such that we can understand it ... it look like this can be solve using `json read` functionality

Comment: what is the source? Is it a csv file, json file, txt file, or a variable being passed to you. Can we have more details? Also, what have you tried so far. Looks like you did try something to get to the result

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

If your initial data is already a dataframe, then you could try something like this:

```
# Use first row values to create a new df
new_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(initial_df.iloc[0]["nutrition per 100g"])
# The iterate over the other rows and append to the new dataframe
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if index == 0:
        continue
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(row.iloc[0])
    new_df.append(temp_df, ignore_index=True)
```